# Serial.println() not working in ISR

Tags: serial, timers

Please refer my below code,

```
const int led_pin = PB5;
const uint16_t t1_load = 0;
const uint16_t t1_comp = 43750;
int blinkcount;



void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  DDRB |= (1<< led_pin);
  TCCR1A = 0;
  //TCCR1B = 0X03;
 TCCR1B |= (1 << CS12);
 TCCR1B &= ~(1 << CS11);
 TCCR1B &= ~(1 << CS10);

  TCNT1 = t1_load;
  OCR1A = t1_comp;

  TIMSK1 = (1 << OCIE1A);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  sei();


}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  delay(500);


}

ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect) {
  TCNT1 = t1_load;
  PORTB ^= (1 << led_pin);
  blinkcount = blinkcount + 1;
  Serial.println(blinkcount);
}
```

the Serial.println(blinkcount); not working or the serial window does not show up.

Apologies if it sound stupid as I'm new to programming.

Comment: please format your code .... you don't print inside ISR .... increment variable and set a second flag variable instead ... check for flag in loop() and print if the flag is set

Comment: thank you for support

Comment: @jsotola can you please review the changed code and share your suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ISR are simply not intended for this abuse.

If you want to use Arduino level functions, you must have good reasons why you need to mix them with direct arv-gcc hardware-accessing code (or vice versa).

If you're new to programming and to Arduino, simply ignore that level (for now).

`DDRB |= BV(PB5);` 
is easier understandable if you write

`pinMode(13,OUTPUT);` ( or even use LED_BUILTIN instead of 13 )

Answer (score 0):

````
const uint16_t t1_load = 0;
const uint16_t t1_comp = 43750;
int blinkcount;
int flag, flag_1, a, i;



void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  DDRB |= (1<< led_pin);
  TCCR1A = 0;
  //TCCR1B = 0X03;
 TCCR1B |= (1 << CS12);  //for 256 prescalar
 TCCR1B &= ~(1 << CS11);
 TCCR1B &= ~(1 << CS10);

/* TCCR1B &= ~ (1 << CS12);
 TCCR1B |= (1 << CS11);
 TCCR1B &= ~(1 << CS10);*/

  TCNT1 = t1_load;
  OCR1A = t1_comp;

  TIMSK1 = (1 << OCIE1A);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  sei();


}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  delay(500);

/*  blinkcount = blinkcount + 1;
  if(blinkcount++)
  {
    flag = 1;
  }
  if(flag == 1)
  {
    Serial.println("ok");
  }*/


}

void loop_1()
{
  i = blinkcount;
  //for(i=0; i<=blinkcount; i++);
  //{
  i = i + 1;
  //if(i++)
  // {
    flag = 1;
    flag_1 = flag;
   //}
  if(flag_1 == 1)
  {
    Serial.println(flag_1);
  }
//  }
}

ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect) {
  TCNT1 = t1_load;
  PORTB ^= (1 << led_pin);
  //blinkcount = blinkcount + 1;
  //Serial.println(blinkcount);
  loop_1();


}```

I've changed the code according to your suggestion, the tx led on arduino blinks but serial monitor does not pop up
````

Comment: loop_1 is (logically) still part of the ISR. **Serial.println() not working in ISR** is a fact, not a question.  Don't use ISRs if you don't need OR understand it. In your case both conditions apply. Sorry.